If Jacob only had that day to gather animals from Laban's flock, how did he get any animals since Laban removed the agreed upon animals that same day?
Genesis 30:32 (ESV) reads thusly, describing the offer by Jacob to Laban:

32 let me pass through all your flock today, removing from it every speckled and spotted sheep and every black lamb, and the spotted and speckled among the goats, and they shall be my wages.

But just a few verses later we read:

35 But that day Laban removed the male goats that were striped and spotted, and all the female goats that were speckled and spotted, every one that had white on it, and every lamb that was black, and put them in the charge of his sons. 36 And he set a distance of three days' journey between himself and Jacob, and Jacob pastured the rest of Laban's flock.

If Jacob's wages were to be the speckled/spotted/striped/black animals he removed that day, but Laban removed that day those very same animals from his flock, how were there any animals left for Jacob?
Later in the chapter we read that Jacob is able to selectively breed the animals in his care to produce speckled/spotted/striped/black animals, but of what use is that to him, since he only has the right to the animals in the flock the day of this agreement, and presumably the animals would have had a gestation period of longer than a day?

Answer
Jacob did not have only that day to gather his prescribed animals from Laban’s flock.
Explanation
The problem mentioned in the OP is related to comprehension only and not to the text itself.
Jacob didn’t tie his condition on “today” but on the “type” of goats and sheep he will collect from Laban’s flock.
Jacob said in effect: “I will go through all your flock today and start removing the speckled and spotted lambs and goats so that they will remain my wages”.
Jacob didn’t say that whatever he removed that day (“today”) will be his. He simply meant he will start doing it that day.
Evidence
If Jacob really meant whatever he collected that day itself belonged to him and nothing else, then he would start immediately to do so because there was an “increased abundance” (verse 30) of flock. Laban would not have gotten any chance to remove any animals because Jacob would have been there already among the flock.
The fact that Laban removed all of such animals that day itself shows that Jacob was nowhere near the flock that day.
So Jacob didn’t mean “today” itself he would collect all the animals. He simply meant, that day onwards he would start collecting his share of the striped and spotted etc animals from Laban’s flock.
Laban’s Character
Jacob knew his uncle-cum-father-in-law very well. He had a terrible experience from him on his marriage day.
This is why, without making any complaints and trusting in God, he selectively bred the required animals from the remaining healthy flock. He could do this because the condition he set was the “type” of animals, not “that day”.
Besides, Jacob also promised Laban that if the latter agreed to him, then he would “again pasture his flock and keep it” (verse 31) staying with him for some more time.
Conclusion
The issue was not “that same day”. The real issue was simply “the type of agreed upon animals”.

This question is based upon a misunderstanding of the narrative.  Let me expand.
Jacob's task in working for Laban and "earning" his wives' bride price was 14 years of managing Laban's farm with its flocks and herds - he was essentially Laban's farm manager and chief shepherd.  Jocob summarized this and his work for Laban over the previous 14 years as follows:

Gen 30:29, 30 - Then Jacob answered, “You know how I have served you
and how your livestock have thrived under my care. Indeed, you had
very little before my arrival, but now your wealth has increased many
times over. The LORD has blessed you wherever I set foot.

By this account, under Jacob's management, Laban had gone from a subsistence farmer to being a very wealthy farmer.
Jacob then asked that the spotted, speckled and streaked sheep be given him as his wages.  Such sheep were considered inferior - presumably because they produced wool of variable color that made fine clothing difficult to produce.  Thus, when Laban agreed to this, he allowed such sheep to be separated from the main flock.
Now, there is a problem with some translations that say, (V35) "But that day Laban removed ..."  The "Problem" here is that the word "Laban" is not in the Hebrew; it is simply a 3rd person masculine singular verb - the pronoun "he" is only implied.  Thus, V35 actually reads (in the Hebrew) -

So he [Jacob] removed on that day the striped or spotted male goats,
and all the speckled or spotted female goats, every one with white on
it, and all the black ones among the sheep, and put them in the care
of his [Jacob's] sons.

This is now consistent with the rest of the narrative.  Versions that have "Laban" (eg, the ESV, BSB, CSB, HCSB, CEVISV, etc) are not being literal, but are interpreting the text.

An apt point to be sure. Thank you for pointing that out, I should have done more translation comparisons. I'd be curious to know what those translators make of this story and how they make sense of this part.
That being said, I don't see how to square your proposed understanding of 35 with 36, which is clearly referencing someone who isn't Jacob. There is no indication the "he" in 36 is a different "he" than 35.
"36 And he set a distance of three days' journey between himself and Jacob, and Jacob pastured the rest of Laban's flock."

@HabelBabel - an apt point and a difficult one.
